# How to fetch username and password from excel one by one to test login functionality in robot framework-selenium-python

Tags: automated-testing, python, robotframework, selenium3, ride

I am trying to login to my application one by one using different credentials in robot framework-python-selenium but it is not working. Below is my code.
Please suggest.

```
Open Browser  ${URL}   chrome
Input Text  id=username   ${user}
Input Text  id=password   ${password} 
${exp_row_count}    get element count   ${PATH_EXCEL}sheet1
${exp_row_count}    evaluate        ${exp_row_count}-1
For    ${i}    IN RANGE     1       ${exp_row_count}

*** Variables ***
${user}        ${i}
${password}    ${i}
${PATH_EXCEL}   C:\Users\TestLogin.xlsx
${i}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what the code you have there do as it is incomplete.

So assuming that you want to do data driven testing, use RobotFramework-datadriver: [Structure of data file](https://github.com/Snooz82/robotframework-datadriver#structure-of-data-file).

**Installation:**

```
pip install --upgrade robotframework-datadriver
pip install --upgrade robotframework-datadriver[XLS]
```

**Create the excell sheet 1.xlsx and keep it in the same directory as .robot file**

[image]

**Now use below robot file:**

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation   This is the script for Create Sales Visit Repository
Library     SeleniumLibrary
Library    DataDriver    file=1.xlsx    sheet_name=Sheet1
Test Template   Run Data Driven Steps

*** Test Case ***
Test Case 1 :Test behavior for Login    temp    temp
    

*** Keywords ***
Run Data Driven Steps
    [Arguments]    ${name}    ${age}
    Log     ${name}
    Log     ${age}
```

**Explanation:**

Robotframework uses Test Template for data driven testing , datadriver leverages this to drive the test using data from excel or csv than hard coding it in test step.

`Library    DataDriver    file=1.xlsx    sheet_name=Sheet1` initialise the data drver with the xlsx file in which we have the data.

`Test Template  Run Data Driven Steps` tells robot that the testcase in suite uses the keyword 'Run Data Driven Steps' as the template. So we defines the test step inside this keyword and not the actual Test Case.

eg:

```
*** Keywords ***
Run Data Driven Steps
    [Arguments]    ${name}    ${age}
    Open ${url}
    Login using     ${1}
    Validate    a==b
```

Now in test case , we call a dummy test case just to trigger the test. The argument is also dummy. But as we say the template `Run Data Driven Steps` excepts two arguments we have to specify two dummy arguments to test case  `Any test name     temp    temp`

**Output:**

**Note:** i used test name as

```
Test Case 1 :Test behavior for Login using ${name} and password ${age}
```

Thats why the data is being printed in the test name

[image]

Comment: Thanks! but where have you define the locator details like in my code                       
(Input Text  id=username   ${user}
Input Text  id=password   ${password} )

Comment: @ADSKUL everything inside the keyword run data ...

Comment: Change the key word to adapt your needs

Comment: Make sure first section after seeing is ***Test Case*** and then ***keyword*** and then variable

Comment: Everything I used same as your code and edit keywords section as below but getting error as 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. I am using chrome and that is already there in PATH. 

*** Keywords ***
Run Data Driven Steps
    [Arguments]    ${Username}    ${Password}
    Open Browser  ${url} chrome
        
    Input Text  id=email   ${Username}
    Input Text  id=email   ${Password                                                                          *** Variables ***
${URL}

Comment: @ADSKUL gecko is Firefox,  u used the same keyword ? Open Browser.       ${url}.      chrome ?

Comment: No, My requirement is chrome and I have added it in PATH. and hence define chrome.

Comment: @ADSKUL add your updated code

Comment: Same code which I have added earlier comments.